# MySql NDB cluster large transaction

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster

I know that with NDB you can not do large transactions, if you do data nodes can restart into read-only mode and corrupt table.

I need to copy records into a new table but the thing is this table contains millions of rows in staging, the live server has even 10 times that amount.

how can I divide my copy into smaller transactions so I will not kill my server?

Comment: Will there be writes (delete/insert/update) against the table while the "copy" is being performed?

Comment: Was it your choice to use NDB?  I ask because that Engine has a rather narrow niche, and a casual user should not pick NDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*ndb_move_data*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-programs-ndb-move-data.html) sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you, seems like exactly what I need (sorry, I can't upvote, not enough rep.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with larger transactions you can increase `MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations`. Default is 32k so in a two node cluster it means that at one time there can be only ~64k rows involved in the transaction.

But also in NDB cluster it is recommended to use smaller transactions anyway. Simplest way usually is by using `LIMIT` clause.

```
 INSERT INTO prod_table SELECT * FROM staging_table LIMIT 10000;
```